# How can I sync data or trigger a Lambda when Cognito user attributes change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda

I'm trying to sync user data (name + some custom attributes) from an AWS Cognito user pool to a DynamoDB table. Cognito has [a lot of triggers related to sign in / sign up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) but I haven't found any trigger that is fired when user attributes are updated.

How can I trigger a Lambda or otherwise sync data when user attributes change?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I store email, family_name and given_name in cognito as part of sign up process. Then users can change any of these fields at any time.

I couldn't find a way to track these changes as the documentation doesn't state any such lambda trigger for sync events. However, since the `idToken` contains the user attributes in my case, it has to update itself after user makes a change. So I tested this and found that the Pre-Token trigger is invoked any time there is a change in the user attributes so that it can regenerate a new token. That lambda contains the following payload

```
{
  version: '1',
  triggerSource: 'TokenGeneration_RefreshTokens',
  region: 'XXX',
  userPoolId: '',
  userName: 'XXX',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown',
    clientId: 'XXX'
  },
  request: {
    userAttributes: {
      sub: 'XXX',
      email_verified: 'false',
      'cognito:user_status': 'CONFIRMED',
      'cognito:email_alias': 'user1@mailinator.com',
      given_name: 'Name',
      family_name: 'New',
      email: 'user1@mailinator.com'
    },
    groupConfiguration: {
      groupsToOverride: [],
      iamRolesToOverride: [],
      preferredRole: null
    }
  },
  response: { claimsOverrideDetails: null }
}
```

So I update the records in dynamodb in this lambda itself. I am not 100% sure though because the documentation doesn't say anything about this use case and pre token trigger. Give it a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar situation but looks Cognito doesn't this scenario yet.

AWS is aware of that but I couldn't found way to track their progress. You can take a look here [AWS thread Trigger Service/Lambda when a Cognito user attribute changes](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266928).

For now what I did its to have a `status` field in the user table at dynamodb, so when I change the data cognito I set this field as false which will trigger a lambda that will get the data from cognito and make the sync.